# telerik radeditor table of contents

Tags: telerik, radeditor, tableofcontents

I want to have a word like table of content in telerik radeditor.
I have enabled it for editing list items,so inside sharepoint's list item dispform,the table of contents should work by scrolling down to correct title.
I tried adding a snippet using anchor tags as below ,but it opens the link in a new window in dispform.
Any ideas?
Thanks

```
 <snippet name="Table of Content">
      <![CDATA[
<a href="#one">One</a>
<br/>
<a href="#two" >Two</a>
<br/>
<a href="#three" >Three</a>
<br/>
<a href="#four" >Four</a>
<br/>
<a href="#five" >Five</a>
<br/>
<a href="#six" >Six</a>
<br/>
<a href="#seven" >Seven</a>
<br/>
<a href="#eight">Eight</a>
<br/>
<a href="#nine">Nine</a>
<br/>
<a href="#ten" >Ten</a>
<br/>


<a name="one" />
<h1>This is number One</h1>
<br/>
<a name="two" />
<h1>This is number Two</h1>
<br/>

<a name="three" />
<h1>This is number Three</h1>
<br/>
<a name="four" />
<h1>This is number Four</h1>
<br/>
<a name="five" />
<h1>This is number Five</h1>
<br/>
<a name="six" />
<h1>This is number Six</h1>
<br/>
<a name="seven" />
<h1>This is number Seven</h1>
<br/>
<a name="eight" />
<h1>This is number Eight</h1>
<br/>
<a name="nine" />
<h1>This is number Nine</h1>
<br/>
<a name="ten" />
<h1>This is number ten</h1>
<br/>

                ]]>
    </snippet>
```